# How to Treat A grouping Variable ID as multiple groups if observations are non-consecutive?

Tags: r

I am working with the following data frame:
[image]
I am wondering how I can treat an ID as multiple different grouping variables if the observations are non-consecutive. So with the above data frame, how can I create the following result? Note how "IndividualID" is treated as different groups if the results are non-consecutive.
[image]

Right now I am using this code:

```
data <- data %>%
  arrange(Team, Game, Minute, IndividualID) %>%
  group_(Team, Game, IndividualID) %>%
  mutate(Count = row_number())
```

But of course this does not produce the intended result.

```
structure(list(Team = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Game = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Minute = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), IndividualID = c(456L, 456L, 322L, 456L, 
456L, 456L, 322L, 322L, 456L, 456L, 456L, 222L, 222L, 115L, 115L, 
222L, 222L, 222L), Count = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to consider consecutive `IndividualID` separately.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, Count2 := seq_len(.N), .(Team, Game, rleid(IndividualID))]
data

#    Team Game Minute IndividualID Count Count2
# 1:    A    1      1          456     1      1
# 2:    A    1      2          456     2      2
# 3:    A    1      3          322     1      1
# 4:    A    1      4          456     1      1
# 5:    B    1      1          456     1      1
# 6:    B    1      2          456     2      2
# 7:    B    1      3          322     1      1
# 8:    B    1      4          322     2      2
# 9:    B    1      5          456     1      1
#10:    B    1      6          456     2      2
#11:    B    1      7          456     3      3
#12:    B    2      1          222     1      1
#13:    B    2      2          222     2      2
#14:    B    2      3          115     1      1
#15:    B    2      4          115     2      2
#16:    B    2      5          222     1      1
#17:    B    2      6          222     2      2
#18:    B    2      7          222     3      3
```

---

This can also be used in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Team, Game, grp = rleid(IndividualID)) %>%
  mutate(Count2 = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup
```

In base R we can use `rle` :

```
transform(data, count2 = ave(IndividualID, Team, Game, 
     with(rle(IndividualID), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = seq_along))
```